# Inserting on many to many relationship setup

Tags: php, mysql, insert, many-to-many

Good day. Newbie here. Would like to ask for help if how would this work? What I want is avoid inserting same names on reference tables(students, lectures) but instead just insert the existing ID in the junction table(student_lecture).

Here is the php:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
$student = $_POST['student'];
$lecture = $_POST['lecture'];

$addStudent = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT IGNORE INTO students (student) VALUES ('$student')");
$studentID = mysqli_insert_id($con);

$addLecture = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT IGNORE INTO lectures (lecture) VALUES ('$lecture')");
$lectureID = mysqli_insert_id($con);

$addClass = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO student_lecture (student_id,lecture_id) VALUES ('$studentID','$lectureID')");

}
```

Here is the html:

```
<html>
<title>Add Class</title>
<body>
<form name="Add Class" method="post" action="<?php echo 
htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
Student: <input type="text" name="student">
</br></br>
Lecture: <input type="text" name="lecture">
</br></br>
<input type="submit" value="Add Class">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[student_lecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVRwY.jpg)

[students](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iebKJ.jpg)

[lectures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrBvl.jpg)

Comment: A few side-notes: 1) You'll want to use different quotes for your `<form>` `action=""` / PHP `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`. 2) Your form is insecure, and vulnerable to SQL injection. Please ensure that you use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent this :)

Comment: You can avoid inserting duplicates by using unique keys on the columns, and using INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE statements. Also, I echo @ObsidianAge comment about using prepared statements.

Comment: Thank you for the comment ObsidianAge regarding the vulnerability of my form, I will look into it. However, for now I want to focus on "Inserting". @SloanTrasher, I've already tried making unique keys on the referenced tables. It works but also it doesn't insert the existing ID on the junction table. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a sql-function that does the inserting for you:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION INSERT_SUDENT_LECTURE(student_title TEXT, lecture_name TEXT)
BEGIN
  SET @m_student_id = -1;
  SET @m_lecture_id = -1;

  /* get student id if exist */
  SELECT s.student_id
    INTO @m_student_id
    FROM student s
   WHERE s.student = student_title;

  /* if not insert */
  IF @m_student_id < 0 THEN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO students (student) VALUES (student_title);

    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
    INTO @m_student_id;
  END IF;

  /* get lecture id if exist */
  SELECT l.lecture_id
    INTO @m_lecture_id
    FROM lecture l
   WHERE l.lecture = lecture_name;

  /* if not insert */
  IF @m_lecture_id < 0 THEN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO lectures (lecture) VALUES (lecture_name);

    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
    INTO @m_lecture_id;
  END IF;

  /* check if all went ok */
  IF @m_lecture_id > 0 && @m_student_id > 0 THEN
    /* insert new values in student_lecture */
    INSERT INTO student_lecture (student_id,lecture_id) VALUES (@m_student_id,@m_lecture_id)
  END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

And then call the function something like this:

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT_SUDENT_LECTURE ('$studentID','$lectureID');");
```

And you should really think about using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) as @ObsidianAge mentioned.
Here for example the call with an prepared statment:

```
$SQL_CONN = mysqli ("host",
                    "user",
                    "password",
                    "dbname",
                    "port");

$stm = $SQL_CONN->prepare("INSERT_SUDENT_LECTURE (?,?);");
$stm->bind_param ("ss", $studentID, $lectureID);

$sqlStm->execute();

$stm->free_result();
$stm->close();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @MadddinTribleD. I would definitely try these methods that you have mentioned. I will look into using prepared statements as mentioned by ObsidiaAge. Since this is new to me, I will take this lightly. Again, thank you.

Comment: A key part of this suggestion is `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. That's generally the best way to obtain the values of autoincremented IDs. Please go read about it. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make it work. Here is the new codes:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    $student = $_POST['student'];   
    $lecture = $_POST['lecture'];

    /* first I have selected the entries from students and lectures table */
    $students = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM students WHERE student='$student'");
    $lectures = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM lectures WHERE lecture='$lecture'");

    /* then fetch every rows */
    $student_row = mysqli_fetch_array($students);
    $lecture_row = mysqli_fetch_array($lectures);

    /* here we check if student name exists */
    if($student == $student_row['student']) {
    /* if it exists then just update it */
    $updateStudent = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE students SET student='$student' WHERE student='$student'");
    }else{
    /* if it doesn't exist then add as new entry */
    $addStudent = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT IGNORE INTO students (student) VALUES ('$student')");
    };

    /* here we check if student id exists */
    if($student == $student_row['student']) {
    /* if it exists then just use existing id */
    $studentID = $student_row['student_id'];
    }else{
    /* if it doesn't exist then use a new id */
    $studentID = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    };

    /* here we check if lecture title exists */
    if($lecture == $lecture_row['lecture']) {
    /* if it exists then just update it */
    $updateLecture = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE lectures SET lecture='$lecture' WHERE lecture='$lecture'");
    }else{
    /* if it doesn't exist then add as new entry */
    $addLecture = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT IGNORE INTO lectures (lecture) VALUES ('$lecture')");
    };

    /* here we check if lecture id exists */
    if($lecture == $lecture_row['lecture']) {
    /* if it exists then just use existing id */
    $lectureID = $lecture_row['lecture_id'];
    }else{
    /* if it doesn't exist then use a new id */
    $lectureID = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    };

    /* then we execute on adding entries on junction table */
    $addClass = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO student_lecture (student_id,lecture_id) VALUES ('$studentID','$lectureID')");

}
```

Thank you for all the response. I've managed to get some ideas. Specially to @MadddinTribleD. It's good being here on StackOverFlow.